# how to use and send email using mime in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift2

I am new to swift and i am using swift version 2.2.

I want to send an email using swift mime. For this, I have go through this link

http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html

But I can not use `require_once 'lib/swift_required.php'` in my swift code.

How can I use this in my osx swift project?

Comment: This "Swift Mailer" thing has nothing to do with Swift, Apple's programming language, it's for PHP.

Comment: @EricD so is there any link or way  to use mime in swift osx to send email ...... thanks

Comment: can anyone give me a link how i can send email from my osx project usign swift ... i search a lot but no result found ... everything is on ios

Answer (score 2):

Apple's [SBSendEmail Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SBSendEmail/Introduction/Intro.html) is documented with a sample project. The interface for the Controller class includes a `sendEmailMessage:` method.

```
@property(retain, readwrite) NSTextField *toField;
@property(retain, readwrite) NSTextField *fromField;
@property(retain, readwrite) NSTextField *subjectField;
@property(retain, readwrite) NSTextField *fileAttachmentField;
@property(retain, readwrite) NSTextView *messageContent;

- (IBAction)sendEmailMessage:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)chooseFileAttachment:(id)sender;
```

Read through the documentation and download the sample project to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer for emails on ios: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28963929/4687211, swift mailer is some php mailer not swift

Comment: i want to do it in osx but in ur link there something in ios