# How to show list of all test bundles under iOS workspace?

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xcodebuild, xcode11

How to show list of all test bundle under iOS workspace?

I am currently running below commands but its showing all configurations,

```
xcodebuild -workspace MyTestWorkspace.xcworkspace -list
```

I want to filter only the test bundles.

Comment: check this
https://stackoverflow.com/q/37676690/8687925
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37971495/8687925

Comment: Are you looking for individual test names or just list of test schemes/plans?   If you're using test plans in Xcode 11, you can use the `-showTestPlans` switch to list the test plan(s) for a scheme.